# Is it possible to see remotely what physical display is showing on linux machine without X?

Tags: linux, console, remote

We can use VNC to connect to remote X session but how can I remotely connect to that session which is displayed on physical monitor if remote linux machine does not have X installed?

UPDATE to make it more clear:
Linux installation has some automation scripts which are run on startup. I would like to know what is going on on headless machine, when it finishes all those scripts, was there any errors or is it waiting for user input.

Comment: Sounds like what you're after is [Lights-Out Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management)

Answer (score 0):

Use screen or tmux to accomplish this. The local user must work inside screen or tmux. Another client connected over SSH can then connect to the same screen/tmux session.

I like to use Ubuntu's Byobu to assist with this. Installing it and then running `byobu-enable` will make Byobu automatically start during every session.

Comment: Linux installation has some automation scripts which are run on startup. I would like to know what is going on on headless machine, when it finishes all those scripts, was there any errors or is it waiting for user input.

Comment: @untitled I think you should add this info to your question, it really makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (question and comment on other answer) you will need something like [PC Weasel](http://electrontubestore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=2323). I'm not advocating PC Weasel, it's just the only thing I've ever heard of that does what you want. It's a PCI video card "which converts VGA to an RS-232 output". Seems like some ugly magic. You'd have to have a second machine or terminal server or something to show you the RS-232 over the network, but the PC Weasel was designed to work just like that.

I don't believe that any network card "PXE" would do what you want, but maybe I'm behind the times. If you don't get a good answer here, update your question to say what you eventually did do, or maybe you just gave up on it. Either way, it would be good info.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hardware solution. Another one would be to use machine with Intel vPro technology which even allows to get into BIOS remotely.

Comment: I am looking for software only solution. I hoped that it's not a big deal for Linux to make something like text mode VNC server.